# Non-virtual method invocation using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

In Java, when working with `java.lang.reflect.Method` how can I invoke a function without it being a virtual call?

I.e. I want this code to print "good" instead of what it currently does, which is print "bad":

Foo.java:

```
public class Foo {
  public void doit() {
    System.out.println("good");
  }
}
```

Bar.java:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Bar extends Foo {
  public void doit() {
    System.out.println("bad");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Bar b = new Bar();
    /* Using Foo.class ought to do it right? */
    Method m = Foo.class.getDeclaredMethod("doit", new Class[]{});
    /* Surely if that didn't do it casting to Foo would? */
    m.invoke((Foo)b, new Object[]{});
  }
}
```

Nothing I do using reflection succeeds in printing "good".

My expectation was that using one or more of casting the first argument of `invoke` to `Foo`, and/or using `Foo.class.getDeclaredMethod` instead of `Bar.class` would be sufficient. Clearly I'm wrong about that, how can I get the desired behaviour still using reflection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the simplest solution is to use the `java.lang.invoke` package, which has a method called `unreflectSpecial` that simulates and invokespecial instruction:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.invoke.*;

public class Bar extends Foo {
  public void doit() {
    System.out.println("bad");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    Bar b = new Bar();
    Method m = Foo.class.getDeclaredMethod("doit", new Class[]{});
    MethodHandle h = MethodHandles.lookup().unreflectSpecial(m, Bar.class);
    h.invoke(b);
  }
}
```

Which does indeed print "good"